# Fastest way of running parallalel python scripts

Tags: python, pandas, bash

What is the fastest way to run multiple python scripts at the same time?

I found two methods, but how would they compare (advantages disadvantages)? and is there any faster way?

method 1) using bash scripts:

```
python pre_process.py --with_some_different_option &
python pre_process.py --with_some_different_option &
... n times
```

method 2) using python:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(n) # or whatever number of cores
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
_= pool.map(pre_process_func, df_list)
```

As a side note, I am trying to pre-process some pandas dataframes (load, process, write)

Comment: Fastest in terms of time spent programming: method 1 plus GNU `parallel`.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to questions of performance, it's always a real comparison with actual implementation and data sets that matters the most.

In this situation, it doesn't make a difference from performance standpoint. Both parallel jobs and `multiprocessing` employ system calls like `fork(2)` and `execve(2)` behind the curtains. You can neglect the overhead in case with python lib. Real question is, where you find parallelization logic suitable for your needs — on job control level in your shell or rather application-side.